# Can't make bison to identify a token - always `$undefined`

Tags: parsing, bison

So I'm currently making a parser with Flex-Bison for python. The lexer part has been completed quite quickly. Here are some parts of the lexer that might be relevant for the current question :

```c
%{
#include <stdio.h>

// many define
#define TOKEN_IDENTIFIER 259
// many define
#define TOKEN_WHITE 294
// many define
#define TOKEN_KEYWORD_FROM 306
// many define
#define TOKEN_KEYWORD_IMPORT 311
// many define

int displayToken(int);
void yyerror(char *sp);

numbers         ((0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.[0-9]+)?)
identifiers     ([a-zA-Z\_][0-9a-zA-Z\_]*)
identation      (^\t+)
whites          (\ |\t|\r|\n)+

// many lines
"from"          { return displayToken(TOKEN_KEYWORD_FROM); }
// many lines
"import"        { return displayToken(TOKEN_KEYWORD_IMPORT); }
// many lines

{identifiers}   { return displayToken(TOKEN_IDENTIFIER); }
{identation}    { return displayToken(TOKEN_IDENTATION); }
{whites}        { return displayToken(TOKEN_WHITE); }

// many lines
.               { yyerror("Unknown token!!!"); }
%%

int displayToken(int token) {

#ifdef DEBUG

// logic to help debug

#endif

    return token;
}
```

Now my parser only tries to parse lines such as :

```py
import math
# or
from math import sqrt
```

So here is my code :

```c
%{
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wimplicit-function-declaration"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int yylex();
%}

%define parse.error verbose

%token TOKEN_KEYWORD_IMPORT TOKEN_KEYWORD_FROM TOKEN_IDENTIFIER TOKEN_WHITE
%start input

%%
input: import_def
     | from_def TOKEN_WHITE import_def
;

import_def: import TOKEN_WHITE identifier;

from_def: from TOKEN_WHITE identifier;

import: TOKEN_KEYWORD_IMPORT {
    printf("found import\n");
};

from: TOKEN_KEYWORD_FROM {
    printf("found from\n");
};

identifier: TOKEN_IDENTIFIER {
    printf("found an identifier\n");
};

%%

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    #ifdef YYDEBUG
    yydebug = 1;
    #endif
    yyparse();
}

int yywrap(void)
{
   return 1;
}

int yyerror(char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s);
    exit(1);
}
```

Afterward, I do those commands:

```bash
flex python.l
bison python.y --debug
gcc lex.yy.c python.tab.c -lfl
./a.out
```

This will prompt my parser, in which I type one of the python `import/from` of earlier. I always get something like this:

```
Starting
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: from math import sqrt
Token ID 306 (TOKEN_KEYWORD_FROM)
Next token is token $undefined ()
error: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting TOKEN_KEYWORD_IMPORT or TOKEN_KEYWORD_FROM
```

So i know that my lexer identifies the token properly, but for some reason the parser seems unaware of that token ID. I've tried to include the `lex.yy.c` into the `python.y` file, without success. I've tried to copy the `define` in both file, without success either. I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token numbers you have hardcoded into your lexer are not the ones that your parser is expecting. Hardcoding token numbers is a terrible idea; it is almost impossible to keep them synchronized between the lexer and the parser. If you got that style out of some kind of so-called "tutorial" or "guide", get rid of it and find a better one.

Bison is designed to make it easy for you to keep these token numbers in synch. Here's what you do:

1. Delete all of those `#define` lines from your lexer. Ask bison to generate a header file:

   ```bash
   bison --defines --debug python.y
   ```
2. Use the generated header (which will be called `python.tab.h`) by putting this line in your lexer just below `#include <stdin.h>`:

   ```c
   #include "python.tab.h"
   ```

   Do not add that include to your parser. Only put it in the lexer.
3. Make sure that you recompile the lexer *every time* you recompile the parser, *after* the parser has created the new header file.

#### Additional suggestions

You can get rid of that `#pragma` line by forward-declaring `yyerror`. The recommended prototype is:

```c
void yyerror(const char* msg);
```

Unless you call `yyerror` yourself, there's no need for a return value; the bison-generated parser does not attempt to use `yyerror`'s return value.

`yyerror` should not call `exit(1)`; that's very unfriendly. If you just let it return, then `yyparse()` will clean itself up and return 1.

You don't need `yywrap`. Insert the following into your lexer prologue:

```
%option noyywrap noinput nounput
```

The first option tells flex not to use the `yywrap` mechanism. The other two tell it not to generate the `input()` and `unput()` static functions, which will let you remove the `#pragma` from your lexer file (you didn't show it, but I suppose it is there somewhere).

It's not recommended for the lexer to call `exit(1)` either (which won't happen if you take that line out of `yyerror`). But you do need to return something from the fallback action. You could return 0, which is equivalent to an EOF, but it's generally better to add to your `%token` list an unused token with a suggestive name (`INVALID_CHARACTER`, for example). Then in your lexer you can `return INVALID_CHARACTER` and you'll get a sensible error message from the parser, without having to invoke `yyerror` yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was under the impression that the lexer was the "source" and that the parser would adapt to the lexer. Everything works properly. Very well explained.